# Was there anything supernatural about Eragon's wound?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

In the novel 'Eragon', the protagonist barely managed to defeat Durza, the Shade who lead the attack on the Varden. Unlike the film version, the battle was largely a contest of wills - what the series refers to as 'a magician duel'. A moment's distraction by Durza allowed Eragon to slay him, but in retaliation he sliced open Eragon's back as he died. The wound was healed, but from that point on Eragon

> was crippled and would often black out from agony when using certain muscles.

This continued throughout his training, and it appeared that no amount of healing or magic would fix the problem - at least not until

> his transformation into an Elf/Human hybrid by the Menoa Tree.

It was often stated that Durza must have done something to make the wound as horrible as it was, but on the other hand it sounds like nerve damage to me.

**Has author Christopher Paolini ever revealed the exact nature of this wound? Was it something like a curse or poison, or was it simply nerve damage from the spine being cut?**

Comment: "his transformation into an Elf/Human hybrid by the Menoa Tree" !!! Eragon was transformed by the dragons, not the Menoa tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There was some magic involved in the wound.

> **Was there anything supernatural about Eragon's wound from Durza, like a curse or poison, or was it simply nerve damage from the spine being cut?**
>
> *There was some magic involved in the wound. (I'm reluctant to say it was supernatural, since magic has a scientific explanation in the world of Alagaësia.)*
>
> <sub>[Reddit AMA 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/Eragon/comments/8fpwfo/i_am_christopher_paolini_ama_starting_2pm_mt/dy6fxwo/?context=3)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Because his painful episodes were usually triggered by moving/bending the wrong way or overexerting himself, it's safe to say there was a significant physical aspect. Some sort of nerve damage or something like that was likely part of it, but magic was also part of it. I'm not sure what the ratio of physical to magical is, but they are both significant.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Obviously there was a physical aspect.  The question, though, is there confirmation of anything *else* to it?  Note that the question is seeking actual statements from the author, not just speculation.